# Div fill height of parent div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a div to fill the remaining height of a div. Here's my HTML and CSS:

CSS:

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#container {
    margin: 85px auto 0px auto;
    background: #444444;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
}
#topbar {
    width: 900px;
    height: 85px;
    background: #555555;
}
#leftbar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;   
    background: #666666;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="topbar">
    </div>
    <div id="leftbar">
    </div>
</div>
```

I expected `leftbar` to fill the height between the bottom of `topbar` and the bottom of `container`, but it's scretching `container` so that `leftbar` is 100% of the page height.

Comment: So I plugged your code into a jsFiddle and got this:  http://jsfiddle.net/KcdYK/

Comment: I am not sure I am seeing a "leftbar" according to your description

Comment: You'd have to set a hard height (rather than min-height) here.  Leftbar should 100% of it's parent's height, but the parent's height is dependent upon leftbar's height??

Comment: The way you have this set up, #leftbar should always be 415px tall

Comment: you can do it without having to use absolute values using my code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stretch the `leftbar` with absolute positioning and setting the `top/bottom` values:

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 85px auto 0px auto;
    background: #444444;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
}
#topbar {
    width: 900px;
    height: 85px;
    background: #555555;
}
#leftbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 250px;
    background: red;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/robertp/CQ7pf/

Comment: the `overflow: hidden` makes it look right, but it will still lose the bottom half of `leftbar` because it's still 100% of the window height

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if I put `topbar` outside of `container`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to container:

```
position: relative;
```

and then add this to leftbar:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it, but then leftbar is taken out of the content flow, and the container is always 85px tall :/

Answer (score 0):

Set your left bar to position: relative;

Answer (score 0):

So `leftbar` should be `container`'s height minus `topbar`'s height. Since `container` and `topbar` have hard-coded height values, it follows that `leftbar` will have to be hard-coded also. It's not the prettiest thing in the world but it's simpler than the alternative, JavaScript.

If `container` is 500px in height, subtract the height of `topbar` (85) and `container`'s margin (85) to arrive at a height of 330px. Since `container` uses `min-height`, use `min-height` for `leftbar` also to allow it to stretch the container if need be. You should also change `leftbar`'s position to relative to render the height of `container` correctly.

Bottom line:

```css
#leftbar {
position: relative;
min-height: 330px;
}
```